# Unable to see marker on map

Tags: android, google-maps

Below is my MapsActivity.java,
I'm trying to getCurrentLocation and place the marker there.
When I run app I am unable to see the marker on my map. What went wrong?
Thanks for the help.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bustracker.usc.myapplication.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager manager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("INSIDE ONCREATE", "TRUE");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        //get the location service
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //request the location update thru location manager
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling

            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            return;
        }
        Log.d("BFORE ISPROVIDERENABLED", "TRUE");
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //get the latitude and longitude from the location
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Log.d("LATLNG", latitude+" " +longitude);
                    //get the location name from latitude and longitude
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses =
                                geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String result = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality() + ":";
                        result += addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ":";
                        result += addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20);
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
        }else if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //get the latitude and longitude from the location
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    //get the location name from latitude and longitude
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses =
                                geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String result = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality() + ":";
                        result += addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ":";
                        result += addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20);
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
        }

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        manager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        Log.i("onPause...","paused");
    }
}
```

Above is my MapsActivity.java,
I'm trying to getCurrentLocation and place the marker there.
When I run app I am unable to see the marker on my map. What went wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: set lat-long in OnMapReady() method..

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the markers and all things about the map inside the `onMapReady` method, if it doesn't work try seeing if you are getting your location properly

Hope it helps you, Pd: sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting valid `latLng`

OR

If you want to add custom icon to set marker add it like:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```